# Detect if the packet was sent in an unauthorized way?

Tags: c#, networking

Some hacking tools inject DLLs to my program, then detects the packets that was previously sent by the client program, then resends it to the server, trying to repeat any action that was done previously by the client. How do I detect those hacking tools, detect any unauthorized repetition of packets, and let the server know this is a hacker??

Comment: Where do you anticipate running this code that will "let the server know this is a hacker"? Bear in mind, if its code running on someone else's machine, you cannot trust it (to operate correctly, to report or not report anything to the server, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking about is called "Man-In-The-Middle-Attack". This is a well known attack type for any network communication. The attacker is intercepting the communication and changing, deleting or repeating packets.
You could try asynchronous encryption. Such algorithms use a private and a public key, one for encryption, the other for decryption. Then put a counter to your packages so if a package is repeated it will have the same counter as the first one.
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92f9ye3s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for further information.

Comment: Thats the idea. Encryption is a tool to prevent unauthorized from reading and/or changing your messages. If the tool resends an encrypted package the content is exactly the same... including the above mentioned message counter. So your partner might receive packages with the same number and can tell that it is the same package.

Comment: Ok, you got it wrong. There is no one in the middle of my connection, there is a dll file injected to the client program that repeats the packet, if the client sends encrypted packets the tool will detect the encrypted packet and resend those encrypted packets!

Comment: Thanks, I got it now!

Comment: That's not a problem. If the package is just repeated add the message counter. You can tell if a package has been repeated if the counter has been the same in another package from this sender.